# Getting "Access to the path is denied" using ASP.net AjaxFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, permissions, ajaxcontroltoolkit, file-permissions

I have a page using the AjaxFileUpload from the AJAX Control Toolkit. The process works fine on my local machine in Visual Studio. However when I publish it to the server the control is displaying **Error** after it's uploaded.

Using the Chrome F12 Developer Tools the failed network call is returning `Access to the path is denied`.

The file is being uploaded to the `windows\temp` folder, so the issue is when the file is copied from there to the the target uploads directly. The C# code is

```
AjaxFileUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + e.FileName));
```

As the developer I don't have access to the server, so I'm speaking to our support to resolve this. I've been told that all the permissions are correct (?).

Is there something in my code that's the issue? If not, what specific permissions that could be missing that I can suggest be checked/changed?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I would check to ensure the **NetworkService** on the server has *READ/WRITE* permissions to the appropriate folders. Also, as good measure, check to insure the application pool your using has the same access as well.